# "Undefined variable: posts" in Laravel 5.8 after post create

Tags: php, laravel

When I create a new Post and hit submit, the post data validates, persists to the database but in the return view I get an `Undefined variable: posts (View:/Users/charles/Desktop/Development/fiestas/resources/views/backend/posts/index.blade.php)` error.

So, it says its undefined, but when I clear the page and visit my index page, the posts show up as they should with no error. I moved over from Rails and am still green at Laravel. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**App/Models/Post.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/Backend/PostController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Post $post)
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('backend.posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('backend.posts.create');
    }

    ...

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'title' => ['required', 'min:3'],
            'body' => ['required', 'min:5']
        ];
        $request->validate($rules);
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $post = new Post();
        $post->user_id = $user_id;
        $post->title = request('title');
        $post->body = request('body');
        $post->save();

        return view('backend.posts.index');
    }
}
```

**routes/backend/posts.php**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Backend\PostController;

// All route names are prefixed with 'admin.'.
Route::redirect('/', '/admin/posts', 301);
Route::get('posts', [PostController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
Route::get('posts/create', [PostController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
Route::post('posts', [PostController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
Route::get('posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
Route::get('posts/{post}/edit', [PostController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');
Route::patch('posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
Route::delete('posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');
```

**resources/views/backend/posts/create.blade.php**

```
...
<form method="Post" action="/admin/posts">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Post Title" value="{{ old('title') }}">
        <textarea name="body" placeholder="Body" id="" cols="30" rows="10">{{ old('body') }}</textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
...
```

**resources/views/backend/posts/index.blade.php**

```
...
@section('content')
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <h5><a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->title }}</a></h5>
        <p>{{ Str::limit($post->body, 100) }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endsection
...
```

Comment: I would think you'd want to do the same thing you do in your index method: get all the posts and send to the view? Or maybe just redirect to the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index method is correct - it grabs the `$posts` variable and compacts it into the return view.

When you are storing a new post, however, you are only storing it, but then calling that same page view through the return statement of the `store()` method *without* the collection:

```
return view('backend.posts.index');
```

You haven't sent the view a `$posts` collection variable from your `store()` method, and your view expects that variable to be there, thus the error.  To fix, within your `store()` method, grab the posts and compact:

```
$posts = Post::all();
return view('backend.posts.index', compact('posts'));
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to redirect after storing the post.
Because the view needs `$posts`.If we simply return to view,it will display error.So we can redirect to index function to retrieve `$posts` and load it in view.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'title' => ['required', 'min:3'],
        'body' => ['required', 'min:5']
    ];
    $request->validate($rules);
    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $post = new Post();
    $post->user_id = $user_id;
    $post->title = request('title');
    $post->body = request('body');
    $post->save();

    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```